# Visualizing that fundamental group is not abelian in general

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

It is well-known that

> The fundamental group of the figure eight is not abelian. i.e. the two ways of composing $a$ and $b$ are not homotopic to each other.

[image]

**Q1:** Why are $ab$ and $ba$ not homotopic? (Edit: this has been [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062396/272127) very nicely)

**Added:**
[image]

**Q2:** Are $ab^{−1}$ in (A) and $ab$ in (B) homotopic?

**Q3:** Why $ab$ in (B) or in above picture is homotopic to a simple loop i.e. a circle? In other words why we are allowed to deform $ca$ in the below to its adjacent image? aren't they welded in the base point?

[image]
img src: [user326210](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3062396)

This is my thoughts: $ab$ is a loop based on the black point which is homotopic to a circle. (For better imagination I consider disc with two hole instead of figure 8.) In the following picture, $ab$ and $ab^{-1}$ are the concatenated loops. Look at the figure (A). there I think $ab^{-1}=b^{-1}a$. i.e. I think $b^{-1}a$ loop is *exactly* same as $ab^{-1}$. But what is wrong here? why they are not homotopic?

**Note:** I am aware about algebraic reasons of why they are not abelian. i.e. [free groups with two generators is not abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305496/272127). I just want to explore that what exactly is happening here. (and correct my misunderstandings)

Comment: What’s your proposed homotopy? (Your diagram A is a little strangely oriented - it looks to me like the directions of the red and blue arrows contradict each other.)

Comment: I don't understand what picture (A) is supposed to be.  Which direction is the loop going? (The two arrows are in opposite directions...)

Comment: Picture A is directed same as first picture above.

Comment: I have drawn such that their directions coincide with [my first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwsqW.png)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I have no idea about that homotopy but their trace are one path. i.e. $ab^{-1}$.

Comment: Shouldn't we fixed a direction for $a$ and $b$ first then start to concatenate them?

Comment: Let $a,b$ correspond to the two canonical inclusions of $S^1$ into $S^1\vee S^1$. Form the loop $\omega=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. This is a map $\omega:S^1\rightarrow S^1\vee S^1$. If $ab\simeq ba$, then $\omega\simeq\ast$ and the mapping cone of $\omega$ (i.e. the adjunction space $(S^1\vee S^1)\cup_\omega D^2$) will be homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^2$. But this space is the torus $S^1\times S^1$ (draw this) and is [not equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371428/prove-that-the-torus-is-not-homotopy-equivalent-to-s1-vee-s1-vee-s2) to $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^2$.

Comment: @Tyrone: I think my problem partly is because i am not understanding the $\omega$ for example too well.  what does it means $ab$? Is it similar to path in the figure (A)? (how many joint point we have? (as I have drawn in (B) there is a jump) one or two? i.e. $ab$ is homotopic to circle or figure 8?)

Comment: You might like to read a little about the [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) of a pointed topological space. Here $ab$ means the concatenation of the loops $a,b$. Similarly $a^{-1}$ means the inverse loop of $a$.

Comment: I know that ($ab$ means the concatenation of the loops $a$,$b$.) what is that exactly mean? my problem is the number of joint points. Just answer this question: Is path in figure (A) "exactly" same as $ab^{-1}$ in [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwsqW.png)?

Comment: 'Joint point' is terminology I've never seen before. I have no idea how you intend to order or orient the loops. If you want to fix your choices so that $(A)$ is $ab^{-1}$, then $(B)$ is $ab$.

Comment: $ab$ in the sense of first image? or figure (A) and (B)? (i meant relation between the loops in figures (A) - (B) and first picture.)

Comment: It seems like you are relying on some vague intuition about how the fundamental group works (which is unclear to others).  I would suggest you instead start from the rigorous definition.

Comment: If you're confused about your notation, how do you think we feel?

Comment: All references explain that $ab$ is traverse $a$ then traverse $b$. But this is vague to me. because I don't know what is the final loop. Is it a figure 8 or a circle? and $aa^{-1}$ that seems should be constant loop, is traverse $a$ then traverse $a^{-1}$ but it is wedge sum of two circles again.

Comment: @EricWofsey: The rigorous definition rely on the understanding the meaning of concatenation $ab$. (sorry for vagueness)

Comment: I have updated the question and I think the problem is clear now.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: identity homotopy doesn't work?

Comment: @C.F.G: if the identity homotopy worked then they'd be the same loop and you wouldn't have proven that anything is abelian...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That is my problem that I think they are same loop. (see the updated question)

Comment: You wrote "I know that $ab$ means the concatenation of the loops $a,b$", and you ask what exactly that means. It means [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Concatenation_of_Paths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loops $ab^{-1}$ and $ab$ are not homotopic.

[image]

Imagine the holes are instead pegs, like the left figure here:
[image: CAD image of two pegs and two holes]
Source:https://www.tinkercad.com/things/11tjAfAiQNw-two-pegs-two-holes

The loop $ab^{-1}$ is equivalent to an open loop $\mathsf{O}$ around both pegs. First, you wrap string around the pegs to make the shape of $ab^{-1}$; tie the start and end of the string into a knot at the base point. Then, notice you can simply nudge the string into an $\mathsf{O}$ shape without moving the base point knot or lifting up the string.

In contrast, the loop $ab$ is different. If you wrap the string around the pegs to make the shape of $ab$, you create a figure $\mathsf{8}$. There is no way to nudge the string into an $\mathsf{O}$ shape without moving the base point or lifting up the string over the pegs.

"Aren't they welded to the base point". Note that you are allowed to nudge *any* part of the string except the knot where the string starts and ends. The string is allowed to cross over itself and cross over the base point. If part of the string crosses over itself at the base point, you can still move that part; just don't move the base knot itself.

---

You can think about homotopies like this to help your intuition. When you make any loop out of string, try nudging the string without (a) moving the base point, or (b) lifting up the string over the pegs. The result is another homotopically equivalent loop, and all homotopically equivalent loops can be made in this way.

The pegs are obstacles. Wrapping a string around them creates a loop that you can't remove unless you lift that loop over the peg. In this way, just by recording which strings can be homotopically transformed into other strings, you can discover where the pegs are, even if the pegs are invisible.  Thus this loop-wrapping approach (homotopy theory) uses strings *within* the space to reveal the invisible obstacles/holes *outside* the space.

Comment: in regard to " just don't move the base knot itself." but in for example $c*a$ [in the image that you drew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQDDb.png) I can simply nudge the below part of $c*a$ (that part that is fixed in your homotopy) and fix the other part (that part that is moving in your homotopy) in base point. So you are saying that I can do these two moves?

Comment: and this part: "except the knot where the string starts and ends". again it is not clear that where is the end point (in a simple loop it is OK but when we concatenate two loops, the start and end of first loop how is related to the start and end of the second loop? I meant after traversing the first loop I can traverse the second loop in two ways i.e. clockwise and counterclockwise (see figs (A) and (B)) which in (A) the end point of $b$ (start of $b^{-1}$) is start point of $a$ and in other  start point of $b$ (end of $b^{-1}$) is end point of $a$).

Comment: Note that all of these variants has been induced from original figure 8 that has no direction.

Comment: When you concatenate two loops together $b\cdot a$, the new loop starts where $a$ starts and ends where $b$ ends, by definition. You can move any part of the string except those endpoints. The definition of a loop like $a$ or $b$ includes an orientation/endpoints, so there's just one unique way to define $b\cdot a$.

Comment: For example, the blue arrow in figure (B) represents loop $b$. The blue arrow in figure (A) represents loop $b^{-1}$, so it should be pointing in the opposite direction. All loops have an orientation (traversal direction), and the inverse loop has the opposite orientation. If you define $b$ as an anticlockwise loop, then $b^{-1}$ must be a clockwise loop.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I appreciate it very much!